# go one step back and one step forward in a loop with python

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, concatenation

I need to loop in a list containing french words and find an asterisk because I want to concatenate the word before the asterisk and the word after the asterisk each time an asterisk appear and continue to the next. 
For example, in the sequence:

```
['les','engage', '*', 'ment', 'de','la']
```

I want to concatenate 'engage' and 'ment' and the output (engagement) should be checked by a dictionary. If in the dictionary, append to a list.

With my code I only get the asterisk:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re


with open ('text-test.txt') as tx:
    text =word_tokenize(tx.read().lower())



with open ('Fr-dictionary.txt') as fr:
    dic = word_tokenize(fr.read().lower())


ast=re.compile(r'[\*]+')
regex=list(filter(ast.match,text))

valid_words=[]
invalid_words=[]

last = None
for w in text:
    if w in regex:
        last=w 
        a=last + w[+1]
        break
if a in dic:
    valid_words.append(a)
else:
    continue
```

Comment: So when concatenated word is found in dictionary, do you want the list to become: `['les','engagement', 'de','la']` or use a different list altogether?

Comment: I want the list to become ['les','engagement', 'de','la'] but only if the result of the concatenation is in the dictionary, otherwise, append to a different list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered how to manage a list (nonsense) like this:

```
words = ['Bien', '*', 'venue', 'pour', 'les','engage', '*', 'ment', 'trop', 'de', 'YIELD', 'peut','être','contre', '*', 'productif' ]
```

So I came u with a method like this:

```
def join_asterisk(ary):
  i, size = 0, len(ary)
  while i < size-2:
    if ary[i+1] == '*':
      yield ary[i] + ary[i+2]
      i+=2
    else: yield ary[i]
    i += 1
  if i < size:
    yield ary[i]
```

Which returns:

```
print(list(join_asterisk(words)))
#=> ['Bienvenue', 'pour', 'les', 'engagement', 'trop', 'de', 'YIELD', 'peut', 'être', 'contreproductif']
```

Comment: that's very good! thanks! This solution only joins the word and does not check if the resultant string is in a dictionary...I need to do that because certainly there will be strings joined that are not words since the asterisk represents the end of a paragraph and I want to connect the words that were separated by line breaks.

Comment: is it possible to check if the result of your concatenation is in a french a dictionary? If so, could you update the code? I have never used Yield so I don't know where to place this check. Thanks

Comment: Oui, @NatáliaResende. For example add a nested `if/else` under if `ary[i+1] == '*':` so, if the joined word is in the dictionary it yields it. Else it `yield ary[i]` and also `yield ary[i+2]`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of thinking "time travel" (i.e. go back and forth), the Pythonic way would be to think functional (time travel has it's place in very resource constrained environments).

One way is to go the enumeration way as @Yosufsn showed. Another is to `zip` the list with itself, but with padding appended on either side. Like this:

```
words = ['les','engage', '*', 'ment', 'de','la'] 
for a,b,c in zip([None]*2+words, [None]+words+[None], words+[None]*2):
    if b == '*':
        print( a+c )
```

Comment: could it be better with `for a,b,c in zip(['']*2+words, ['']+words+[''], words+['']*2):` ? to avoid error in case  list begins or ends with a *

Comment: @PRMoureu: Depends on the desired semantics. If a `*` at the head or end of a list is expected data, then yes, that would be the right choice. Otherwise it might be desireable an exception to actually be raised.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a simple code like this:

```
words = ['les','engage', '*', 'ment', 'de','la']

for n,word in enumerate (words):
    if word == "*":
        exp = words[n-1] + words[n+1]
        print (exp)
```

Output:

```
"engagement"
```

With this output, you can subsequently check with your dictionary.

Comment: careful if the list begins or ends with a `*`

Comment: Thank you very much. My list is much bigger than this one. This list in my post was just to illustrate the problem. Does the code work for a bigger list?

Comment: @PRMoureu, why did you use 'enumerate'?

Comment: He did so to obtain an index for each word. `enumerate` will return `(0, 'les'), (1,'engage'),....`

Comment: @PRMoureu, I understand now why you used enumerate. I think this code also works for a bigger list, right?

Comment: yes, but if you have some lists ending with `*` this code will crash. If the list begins with `*`, you will get a wrong result too (`"lales"` in this example). And you may need to handle this kind of cases too :`['les','engage', '*', '*', '*', 'ment', 'de','la']`